# RHF not resetting values in an MUI checkbox group

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to reset my form with the `reset()` method and, it is working partially. All of the form's fields get reset, except for the checkboxes group.

I have tried three different ways of implementing an MUI `CheckboxesGroup` but, I always get the same result.

You can see a working example in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-checkbox-group-9tu0d)

**Checkbox one implementation**

```
<FormControl error={error} required={required} component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        render={({ field: { onBlur: rhfonBlur, onChange: rhfonChange } }) => (
          <FormGroup onBlur={rhfonBlur}>
            {Object.keys(options).map((key) => {
              return (
                <FormControlLabel
                  label={key}
                  key={key}
                  control={
                    <Checkbox onChange={(e) => rhfonChange(handleCheck(key))} />
                  }
                />
              );
            })}
          </FormGroup>
        )}
        control={control}
      />
      <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
```

**Checkbox two implementation**

```
<FormControl error={error}>
      <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
      <FormGroup>
        {Object.keys(options).map((key) => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel
              key={key}
              control={<Checkbox {...register(name)} />}
              value={key}
              label={key}
            />
          );
        })}
      </FormGroup>
      <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
```

**Checkbox three implementation**

```
<FormControl required error={error} component="fieldset" variant="standard">
      <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field: { onChange: rfhonChange, value } }) => {
          // console.log("value:", value);
          return (
            <FormGroup>
              {Object.keys(state).map((key) => {
                return (
                  <FormControlLabel
                    label={key}
                    key={key}
                    control={
                      <Checkbox
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          rfhonChange(handleChange(e));
                        }}
                        checked={state[key]}
                        name={key}
                      />
                    }
                  />
                );
              })}
            </FormGroup>
          );
        }}
      />
      <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third implementation was the correct way of doing it by using RHF's `<Controller />` component. The reason why it wasn't working was because of the following:

- you're not updating RHF's internal state for your field as you are only passing a function to the `onChange` handler. There is no need to use an additional `useState` here
- your initial value is a boolean (`false`) but you are using an object inside the `<CheckboxThree />` component

So basically you can simplify the component to the following (in you're example it isn't clear if the field value should be an object or an array containing the selected options - so the example i made is using an array):

```js
const CheckboxThree = ({
  control,
  error,
  helperText,
  label,
  name,
  options
}) => {
  return (
    <FormControl required error={error} component="fieldset" variant="standard">
      <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref, ...field } }) => (
          <FormGroup>
            {Object.keys(options).map((key) => {
              return (
                <FormControlLabel
                  label={key}
                  key={key}
                  control={
                    <Checkbox
                      {...field}
                      name={key}
                      checked={value.some((option) => option === key)}
                      onChange={(event, checked) => {
                        if (checked) {
                          onChange([...value, event.target.name]);
                        } else {
                          onChange(
                            value.filter((value) => value !== event.target.name)
                          );
                        }
                      }}
                      inputRef={ref}
                    />
                  }
                />
              );
            })}
          </FormGroup>
        )}
      />
      <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit reset-checkbox-group (forked)]

Comment: Thank you so much @knoefel. This solution works like a charm!